# PHP 8.1.2 - Unusual behavior with DOMDocument when saving and formatting XML data

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am trying to output some configuration data to an XML file using DOMDocument and the code below using loadXML(), saveXML() and save(), however the XML file always has a structure like below (notice **Configuration/**, but not **Configuration /Configuration**), and I cannot get XML indentation to work using preserveWhiteSpace = false and formatOutput = true. Where is "**Configuration/**" coming from, and why no closing clause after Authentication_Key_2?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration/>
<FullProductName>Text</FullProductName>
<Copyright>Text</Copyright>
<Version>Text</Version>
<Website>Text</Website>
<Database_Password>NDE2NDYxNmQ0ODZmNmU2NTZiMzEzOTM4MzE=</Database_Password>
<Authentication_Key_1>MDY0ZmRhMDYwYzkxMjVkNzk1M2U4YzUx</Authentication_Key_1>
<Authentication_Key_2>ZjllYWFjYmQ5NTEyYmNiNWE4MmYwZj==</Authentication_Key_2>
```

The code I'm using follows below:

```
//Create the config data structure.
$new_config_data = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8"); 


$config_xml_element_name[0] = "Configuration";
$config_xml_element_name[1] = "FullProductName";
$config_xml_element_name[2] = "Copyright";
$config_xml_element_name[3] = "Version";
$config_xml_element_name[4] = "Website";
$config_xml_element_name[5] = "Database_Password";
$config_xml_element_name[6] = "Authentication_Key_1";
$config_xml_element_name[7] = "Authentication_Key_2";                   


$config_xml_element_instance[0] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[0]); 
$config_xml_element_instance[1] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[1], $FullProductName);
$config_xml_element_instance[2] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[2], $ThisProductSoftwareHouse);  
$config_xml_element_instance[3] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[3], $ThisProductVersion);
$config_xml_element_instance[4] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[4], $ThisProductWebsite);
$config_xml_element_instance[5] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[5], $_POST['postgresql-password']);
$config_xml_element_instance[6] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[6], $_POST['secret-key1']);  
$config_xml_element_instance[7] = $new_config_data->createElement($config_xml_element_name[7], $_POST['secret-key2']);

//Go through array of config file elements and append them to data structure
for ($config_xml_element_id = 0; $config_xml_element_id < count($config_xml_element_instance); $config_xml_element_id++) {
                            
        //If this is the Root element then append it to config data structure as Root 
        if ($config_xml_element_id == 0) {
            
            $new_config_data->appendChild($config_xml_element_instance[0]);                         
            
        //Otherwise append it to config data structure as Child element of Root element
        } else {
            
            $config_xml_element_instance[0] = $new_config_data->appendChild($config_xml_element_instance[$config_xml_element_id]);                          
            
        }
        
}

$Config_create_file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .$ParentProductRootPath .$ParentProductSubPath .$ThisProductTopPath ."/Application/Config/";
$Config_create_file = ucfirst($ThisProductFilePrependName) ."_config.xml";  
$Config_create_file_string = $Config_create_file_path .$Config_create_file;

    
//If the Config directory does not exist then create it
if (!file_exists($Config_create_file_path)) {
mkdir($Config_create_file_path, 0777, true);
}
            

//Save compiled config data structure to XML file       
$ConfigDataXml = $new_config_data->saveXML();
$new_config_data->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$new_config_data->formatOutput = true;  
$new_config_data->loadXML($ConfigDataXml);
$new_config_data->saveXML();                
$config_write = $new_config_data->save($Config_create_file_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding all of the nodes into the root of the document, so there is no hierarchy and there is no content for the Configuration node (as it's empty it shows `'.

I think the line which is the problem is where you add from element id after 0...

```
$config_xml_element_instance[0] = $new_config_data->appendChild($config_xml_element_instance[$config_xml_element_id]);
```

Is adding the new element onto the root of the new document.  To add it to the configuration element, add it to `$config_xml_element_instance[0]`...

```
$config_xml_element_instance[0]->appendChild($config_xml_element_instance[$config_xml_element_id]);
```

Comment: Excellent catch!! The miracles a fresh pair of eyes can do!! Thank you Nigel!! In other words I was appending the children onto a root to which I wasn't passing a valid reference to. So logical once the syntax typo is obvious.